# Google Geo Location and Radius

Tags: php, google-maps

I currently have a search field where a user would search either postcode,town or county for properties.

I obtain the Geo locations from Google Places to do a radius search.

However. If i search or all properties in a county and the Geo location (long and lat) is central to that county and the county is 200 miles in radius and i set the max radius to 1 mile. How would that work?

The end result i would want to include the counties within a 1 mile radius to all the borders of the desired county.

So my question is, using Google places; how would one search within a radius of a large town or county?

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: sorry are you uses mysql to store lat,lon? if yes then my answer will helps you

Answer (score 1):

use this one that will help

```
$query1 = "SELECT 3956*2*SIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((".$latitude." - latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)+    COS(".$latitude."*pi()/180)*COS(latitude*pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((".$longitude." - longitude)* pi()/180/2),2))) as distance FROM tbl_babble HAVING distance < ".$radius." "
```

Apply radius to `$radius` vadiable and set obtained `latitude` and `longitude` to the according variable.

**EDIT**

for more reference go through this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your comment however it dosnt address the issue. let me explain. The long and lat values on the east of the towns border will be different to the long and lat to the center or west border.

Comment: The only resolve i can think would be to have 12 geo locations (imagine a clock face and each number represents  point) but how would one obtain the 12 geo locations from a centeral point?

Comment: taking on your clock face example: first try with given query in the incremental loop and every time add +1 radius and when you get your all 12 point then break loop. Let me know if you have still confusion

Comment: how would one automatically populate the 12 points. If i searched for lets say London; i would want the 12 points to automatically populate with the geo location borders of london and then if i search manchester then for the same to happen and so on and so forth

Comment: I am afraid google is not providing such functionality like I search for New york then it automatically decides the New York's border and filter your data within that radius.

Comment: yes welcome but tom I have one working suggestion, you can get the boundary of your map and search your stores within the boundary which helps you to get optimise data with better performance.